# how to setup maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to learn maven. So here is what I did.

```
1) Open eclipse.
2) New Project
3) create a package org.bar.foo;
4) Say thats all in my project and it has 3 files.. foo.java, bar.java and foobar.java
```

Now, when I look at my directory structure... it looks like

```
-src--org--bar--foo --all the files are here
```

Now.. on the top level next to src. I add a pom file..

I do mvn clean package.. Test passes..

But when I try to execute the jar, I get an error(class not found).

Turns out maven likes the directory structure to be

```
src--main--java--org--bar--foo.. and so on..
```

But now.. eclipse complains. change the package name from

```
org.bar.foo to main.java.org.bar.foo
```

I am trying to follow this example
https://github.com/xamry/hadoop-examples

Comment: Maybe Eclipse can directly create a maven project like Netbeans. Look at New Project dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you right click on eclipse top project, you can convert it to maven project, which I recommend.

[image]

Another way to do is to create a scratch project with `mvn archetype:generate`.

Comment: I dont see "convert to maven project" option.. is that a plugin i need to download?

Comment: ofc, you need to install a plugin for eclipse to work with maven project, eclipse does not come with it.